# I am receiving a 500 internal server error for my GET request in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to display the user's saved recipes by attaching a usersID with the recipeID. when I make the GET request. I'm getting back an empty object with no properties. What exactly is going on with this code?

Here are the savedRecipe routes:

```
router.get('/savedRecipes/ids/:userID', async (req, res) => {

    const {userID} = req.params
    try {
        const user = await UserModel.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID));
        res.status(201).json({ savedRecipes: user?.savedRecipes });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
})


router.get('/savedRecipes/:userID', async (req, res) => {

    const {userID} = req.params

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID));
        
        const savedRecipes = await RecipeModel.find({
          _id: { $in: user.savedRecipes },
        });
    
        console.log(savedRecipes);
        res.status(201).json({ savedRecipes });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write `UserModel.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID))`,
just write `UserModel.findById(userID)`

I assume that "savedRecipes" is an Array of "Recipe _ids" like `["64aaea3d0ce4282f14604767", "64aaea3d0ce4282f1460476s"]` this,

So the problem is here,

```
const savedRecipes = await RecipeModel.find({
      _id: { $in: user.savedRecipes },
});
```

Here `_id` is Mongoose ObjectId and user.savedRecipes is an `Array of Strings`

You can't compare `Strings` with `Mongoose ObjectID`. So save the recipe _ids as `Mongoose ObjectID` in the "savedRecipes" Array.

To save the id as Mongoose ObjectId, change the Schema like this,

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     //...
     savedRecipes: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId]
})
```

Or use `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(recipeID)` when saving it to the `savedRecipe` array.